# The homogeneity of error variance in MMR with continuous moderator?

Tags: interaction

I was wondering if I have to worry about the homogeneity of error variance assumption (which states that the predicted scores for Y should be similarly distributed about the regression line for each of the moderator based populations) when my moderator is continuous?  I know you should not dichotomize a continuous moderator but that is the only way I would be able to get "moderator-based" subgroups.  I have found literature on how to test this when the moderator is categorical and I am not sure if it is something I have to worry about.  If I do have to check this assumption how would I go about it?  Thanks.

Comment: What does MMR stand for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use heteroskedasticity robust standard error estimators, e.g. White's estimator, when you suspect the homoskedasticity assumption. White's test can also be used to test the homoskedasticity assumption.